# How do I avoid nested loops when building a nav?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a JSON file that stores data for a navigation panel (links). A short version is below:

```
[
    {
        "category": "Pages",
        "links": [
            {
                "url": "#",
                "caption": "Account",
                "dropdown": [
                    {
                        "url": "profile.html",
                        "caption": "Profile"
                    },
                    {
                        "url": "edit-profile.html",
                        "caption": "Edit Profile"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "url": "orders.html",
                "caption": "Orders"
            },
            {
                "url": "faq.html",
                "caption": "FAQ"
            }
        ]
    },
    ...
]
```

So when I build an HTML code for those links with jQuery I have 3 nested `for` loops:

- 1 for categories
- 1 for links inside that category
- 1 for possible dropdown links

The code is below:

```
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    ...
        for(var n = 0; n < data[i]["links"]; i++) {
            ...
            for(var k = 0; k < data[i]["links"][n]["dropdown"]; k++) {
                ...
            }
        }
   }
```

Even that the code works, I heard that nested `for` loops are no good (also the code looks a bit scary). Is there a way to replace it? Will that new way make the code run faster?

Comment: sometimes, nested loops can't be avoided without jumping through unnecessary hoops. In this case, you actually have to work on each key/value pair one at a time anyway so even if you did find a way to flatten it, it wouldn't actually result in less work. Nested loops are only a problem when it results in hitting the same piece of data multiple times needlessly.

Comment: This looks like a job for a recursive function

Comment: Agree with @J.Titus.  You could create a recursive algorithm to flatten the object, then use the flattened object in a single loop.

Comment: heh, i would argue that flattening it would be more work. First you'd have to iterate over all (or some) of the key/value pairs to flatten it, then you'd have to loop over the flattened structure, thus hitting some (or all) data points twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets assume you have:

- 'n' items in your root array
- 'm' links per item in the root array, and
- 'o' items in dropdown per link

Your current solution is `O(nmo)`. No matter how you re-write the code, you cannot optimize your time complexity better than this. This is because you absolutely need to visit every element once, and optimizing beyond `O(nmo)` implies you skip some elements.

> Nested for loops are no good

This is a bit of a generalization. To be more specific, nested for loops are no good when nested for loops are not needed. In your case, they are needed.

You could re-write for readability etc., but you're at the best case performance right now.

Comment: That's the answer I wanted to see (no need to rewrite the code). Thanks!